# False positive using string.length in if statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I'm trying to format phone numbers.  Perhaps my approach is not the best but it works with the exception of some unexpected behavior.  I'm using string.length in an if statement to see if the phone number's length (stored as a string) is greater than 9.  I've also tried >= 10 instead of > 9 with the same results.  All works fine with 18001234567 or 7041234567.  I get (800) 123-4567 or (704) 123-4567.  But with 828464047 I get (82) 846-4047 rather than the number just being returned as is.

```
try
{
    if (ANI.Length > 9)
    {
        char[] Number1 = { '1' };
        ANI = ANI.TrimStart(Number1);
        return String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", Convert.ToDouble(ANI));
    }
    else if (ANI == "")
    {
        return "Private";
    }
    else
    {
        return ANI;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

Any ideas?  Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks.

If I change the code that formats the phone number to use substrings, things break, as expected.

```
return "(" + ANI.Substring(0, 3) + ") " + ANI.Substring(3, 3) + "-" + ANI.Substring(6, 4);
```

An exception is caught and "Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length"  is returned.

Comment: Is there a space in your sample number? You may want to `.Trim()` prior to testing length.

Comment: Do not catch the base `Exception` class, this is very bad practice.

Comment: Your claim cannot be correct given this sample code, or you are using different code. Please provide a short sample that reproduces the problem

Comment: I'm curious, when you are debugging this what does it think ANI's length is? I notice you are trimming it so does that mean it could be `"      12345678"` (with lots of spaces at the beginning, not just the one this seems to show) which is of course longer than length 9?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was stripping the leading '1' after having evaluated the length of the string.  Stripping the '1' bef

Answer (score 4):

I put it into a unit test method and it works.  You're obviously getting an extra character added onto the string 828464047.  You can debug and place a breakpoint at the IF statement and see what is actually in ANI.

A few things as well,

- Don't name a variable something ambiguous like "ANI".
- rename Number1 to something like "firstNumber"
- A **try/Catch** is not needed for this statement, if you're getting an exception you're doing something that can be solved by better coding.

Answer (score 3):

I can see `ANI.TrimStart()` in your code which leads me to suspect that you have some leading whitespace. You can probably best solve the problem by moving the trimming to outside the `if`.

It's pretty safe to assume that something as fundamental as `String.Length` works correctly. When it says your string is a certain length, your string really will be that length.

Comment: It also would be better to use Trim() which trims start and end.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check your inputs for whitespace or, perhaps you transcribed your input wrong here.  The following tests pass against your code, copied and pasted:

```
    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void Ten_Digit_800_Number()
    {
        var myPad = new NumberFormatter();

        Assert.AreEqual<string>("(800) 123-4567", myPad.FormatNumber("18001234567"));
    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void Ten_Digit_800_Number()
    {
        var myPad = new NumberFormatter();

        Assert.AreEqual<string>("(800) 123-4567", myPad.FormatNumber("18001234567 "));
    }

    [TestMethod, Owner("ebd"), TestCategory("Proven"), TestCategory("Unit")]
    public void TroubleString()
    {
        var myPad = new NumberFormatter();

        Assert.AreEqual<string>("828464047", myPad.FormatNumber("828464047"));
    }
```